# Unable to assert a value in Cypress

Tags: cypress, assertion

I have an input field where I type the value 1000, and when I try to assert the value, the assertion fails:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WVhK.png

My code `cy.get('#insurance_cover_money').type(1000).should('have.value', '1 000')`

HTML: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KS7b.png

Thank you!

Comment: Strange how your DOM element doesn't reflect the input value in your HTML screenshot. Also, there are sometimes hidden characters (not just spaces) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```js
cy.get('#insurance_cover_money').type('1000').should('have.value', '1000')
```

If the above is still not working you can do two things:

1. Log the value and then copy-paste it into the should assertion.

```js
cy.get('#insurance_cover_money')
  .type('1000')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((val) => {
    cy.log(val)
  })
```

2. Extract the value in the first get and then pass the same value pass into the should assertion.

```js
cy.get('#insurance_cover_money')
  .type('1000')
  .should('not.have.value', '0')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((val) => {
    cy.get('#insurance_cover_money').should('have.value', val)
  })
```

You can also try increasing the timeout:

```js
cy.get('#insurance_cover_money', {timeout: 8000})
  .type('1000')
  .should('have.value', '1000')
cy.get('#insurance_cover_money', {timeout: 8000})
  .type('1000')
  .should('have.value', '1 000')
```

In case you want to remove spaces and assert, you can do like this:

```js
cy.get('#insurance_cover_money')
  .type('1000')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((val) => val.replace(/\s/g, ''))
  .should('eq', '1000')
```

Comment: This doesn't work:
assertexpected <input#insurance_cover_money.form-control> to have value '1000', but the value was 1 000

Comment: This gives a compiling error, you can't write just 1 000

Comment: Instead of 1000 send '1000' with `cy.get('#insurance_cover_money').type('1000')`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not quite what I need.

Comment: Updated the answer with removing spaces, in case you want to check out.

Comment: Thank you! This one is what I needed:
```cy.get('#insurance_cover_money')
  .type('1000')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((val) => val.replace(/\s/g, ''))
  .should('eq', '1000')```

Answer (score 0):

So all I needed to do, is to remove the spaces inside the string, and then do the assertion:

```js
cy.get('#insurance_cover_money').type(1000).invoke('val').then(value => {
   const string = value.replace(/\s/g, '') // removes the spaces inside a string
   expect(string).to.equal('1000')
        })
```